# In netty what progress and total represents in progresive listener

Tags: netty

Please explain any one, what progress and total variables represents in operationProgressed method of ChannelProgressiveFutureListener iterface, is it represents total no bytes transfered, following is the code and its output results:

```
 ChannelFuture future = channel.writeAndFlush(bodyRequestEncoder, channel.newProgressivePromise());
            future.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {

                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("progress : " + progress + " of total: " + total);

                }
            });
```

and console output:

```
progress : 1 of total: -1
progress : 2 of total: -1
progress : 3 of total: -1
progress : 4 of total: -1
progress : 5 of total: -1
progress : 6 of total: -1
progress : 7 of total: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `progress` is the progress in per cent and `total` is "the number that signifies the end of the operation when progress reaches at it. -1 if the end of operation is unknown".

Have a look at the [Netty API Documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/GenericProgressiveFutureListener.html#operationProgressed%28F,%20long,%20long%29).

Comment: but progress was until 7 still it does not specifies 100 percent completion